# Microsoft Access: Adding items in a grouped query?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Query I'm grouping from looks like this..

```
FirstName|LastName|SSN|CheckNo|CheckDate|CheckAmt|Description|
Stone    |Striclan|271-1397543|131292223|-2000.78|FICA       |
Stone    |Striclan|271-1397543|131292223|-2000.78|FICA       |
Stone    |Striclan|271-1397543|131292223|20000.78|Cost of Lab|
```

Trying to create the grouped query...

```
FirstName|LastName|Description|Sum of Payment Types
Stone    |Striclan|FICA       |-4001.56
Stone    |Striclan|Cost of Lab|20000.78
```

Where the query is grouped by description and with the sum of the checkAmt's of description. I can't seem to figure out how to go about creating the Sum of Payment Types part, any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Description, SUM(CheckAmt) As 'Sum of Payment Types'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Description
```

Comment: And then how would I go about creating a new query with the first name, last name, and total pay? Total pay in my above example would be the sum of all payments for one name. So the total pay would be 15999.22

Comment: bad attitude, adding requirement on the go. I'm not going to update my answer for that. Ask one *very specific* question at a time.